# how to retrieve the most entered value from SQL Server database?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ado.net

if i have mssql database with record displayed below :

```
Id           Serv-code          Value
1            100                3
2            100                4
3            100                3
4            100                3
5            101                5
6            101                5
```

the logic i want when i search for the record using serv_code 100 then the output will be the average means 3 will be displayed in textbox because the value 3 will be entered 3 times than 4 as shown above .... and if if i search record with serv_code 100 and if the value of serv_code is equal means 3 and 4 only then the recent entered value will be displayed in textbox..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing. But to answer the part with the average value:
you should do this on database side with the [AVG-SQL-Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
Id              int,
ServCode        INT,
Value           INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp Values(1,100,3)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values(2,100,4)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values(3,100,3)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values(4,100,3)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values(5,101,5)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values(6,101,5)

select AVG(Value)FROM #Temp WHERE ServCode=100

drop table #Temp
```

Use this to create an extra column in your query with the average of every row's Serv-Code:

```
 SELECT  T1.*,
    (SELECT AVG(Value)
        FROM [#Temp] AS T2
    WHERE T1.ServCode=T2.ServCode) AS average
 FROM [#Temp] AS T1
```

Comment: Because you wanted the average-value of all records with serv-code=100 (3). Create a user defined function in your sql-server that takes the Serv-Code as parameter and returns the average value. Then you can compare the old value with the new value that the user wants to set or whatever.

Comment: can i use directly average function with select query ?

Comment: which datatype is use in database to use AVG value ?

Comment: edited my answer to show you how to add the extra average-column.

Comment: What is t1 and t2 i have only one table !!

Comment: What would i do to edit your select query to perform operation in single table ..

Comment: The result is only one table(T1 in my example, you can call it whatever you like), T2 is only to join every record with its average result. You cannot use an aggregat function like AVG without grouping the other columns. But because you don't want to group by the average i needed T2.

Answer (score 0):

```
with occurrences as (select value, occurrences, rank() over(order by occurrences desc) as rank
                     from (select value, count(*) as occurrences
                           from @data where serv_code = 101 group by value
                          ) count_occurrences
                     )
select case when (select count(*) from occurrences where rank = 1) > 1
            then (select top 1 data.value from @data data join occurrences on data.value = occurrences.value where data.serv_code = 101 and occurrences.rank = 1 order by id desc)
       else (select value from occurrences where rank = 1)
       end as value;
```